# Insert new line with value when not value at all is found

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to find here some previous question that I can use but unfortunately can't find my exact case.

I would like to get from the output of another command that looks like this:

```
pattern.d
17.91
17.55
pattern.b
pattern.a
7.21
9.34
pattern.c
```

to this:

```
pattern.d
17.91
17.55
pattern.b
1000
pattern.a
7.21
9.34
pattern.c
1000
```

I try to explain a bit more:
After every line that contains the string "pattern" there should always be a number. If not, I would like to insert a new line with the value 1000.

Note that pattern has an "extension" (.a .b .c .d but not numbers in the "extension") that varies and it will help me to sort alphabetically the contents later on.

EDIT: I have accepted an answer, but in case someone wants to still look for another variation, I should specify that the occurrence of "pattern" varies, and there could be more than 2 or 3 consecutive ones, like in:

```
pattern.a
pattern.d
pattern.c
pattern.d
pattern.b
17.91
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `sed` solution that'll work with any input (e.g. multiple consecutive lines matching `pattern`):

```
sed '1{                   # when on first line
x                         # exchange
s/^/1000/                 # replace the empty hold buffer with "1000"
x                         # exchange back
}
: do                      # label "do"
/pattern/{                # if the current line matches "pattern"
${                        # if we're on the last line
G                         # append hold buffer content to pattern space
b                         # go to end of script
}
n                         # otherwise print and pull in the next line
/^[[:digit:]]/!{          # if this one doesn't start with a digit
x                         # exchange
p                         # print (the pattern space is now "1000")
x                         # exchange back
b do                      # go to label "do"
}
}' infile
```

With `gnu sed` it can be written as

```
sed '1{x;s/^/1000/;x};:b;/pattern/{${G;b};n;/^[[:digit:]]/!{x;p;x;bb}}' infile
```

You can do something similar with `awk`:

```
awk -vc=0 '!/^[[:digit:]]/{
if (c) {print "1000"}
}
{ if (/pattern/){c=1} else{c=0}
}
END{if (c){print "1000"}
};1' infile
```

that is, set `c=1` on lines matching `pattern` and `c=0` on the rest of the lines and on each line that doesn't start with a digit (as well as in the `END` block) check if `c` is set (or `1` - meaning the previous line matches `pattern`) - if so print `1000`.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this as I prefer the command in one line, but kudos to the rest of people who took the time to look for a solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '
   $!{
      /pattern\.[a-z]/N
      /\n/!b
      /\n[+-]\{0,1\}[.][0-9]\{1,\}$/b
      /\n[+-]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\([.][0-9]*\)\{0,1\}$/b
      h;s/\(.*\n\).*/\11000/p
      g;D
   }
   /pattern\.[a-z]/a\
1000
' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
pattern.d
17.91
17.55
pattern.b
1000
pattern.a
7.21
9.34
pattern.c
1000
```

---

### Working

- While not at eof `$!{...}` we append the next line to the pattern space on the condition that the current line is a line of interest.
- Then we skip any further processing in cases of:
  a) No newline found => no pattern in the current line.
  b) A floating point number of the format .nnn in the second line.
  c) A floating point number of the format mmm, mmm., or mmm.nnn is found exclusively on the second line.
  d) Barring any of the possibilities => we need to add the magic number 1000 to the next line's end after the newline.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /pattern/) {      # if it's a `pattern` line
         if ((getline nl) > 0) {  # check if next record exists
             # if next record hasn't number - insert `1000`, otherwise - print current and next records as they are
             print ((nl !~ /^[0-9]/)? $0 ORS 1000 ORS nl: $0 ORS nl)
         } else {
             print $0 ORS 1000   # if the file ends up with pattern - insert `1000`
         } 
       } else {
          print $0  # print other record
       }
    }' file
```

The output:

```
pattern.d
17.91
17.55
pattern.b
1000
pattern.a
7.21
9.34
pattern.c
1000
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make this work, I received some syntax errors but maybe it's me not doing it properly.

Comment: @demklad, yes, I also think that you not doing it properly

Answer (score 0):

If there are never more than two back-to-back instances of `pattern`, and you have GNU sed, then:

```
sed '/^pattern/ {$!N; /\n[0-9]/b; s/$/\n1000/M}' file
pattern.d
17.91
17.55
pattern.b
1000
pattern.a
7.21
9.34
pattern.c
1000
```

How it works:

- if the current line starts with `pattern` then

  - provided we are not at EOF, append the next line
  - if there is a digit following the newline (this could be made more specific) then `b`ranch out (i.e. continue to the next line); else
  - substitute the first line ending with a newline and `1000`

The GNU-specific `M` modifier allows `$` to match either `\n` or `$` so that it handles both the "normal" case and the EOF case where no following line is appended.

Comment: As you said, it doesn't work with more than two back-to-back instances of pattern
It is random, but it can occur in my case. I should have specified that it could be a possible case scenario. Thanks though